# virtualizing a .net application

Tags: virtualization, .net-framework

My professor ask me to create an application and it will be run on a machine without .NET installed.

My application utilizes .NET 4.0 (just basic c# necessites but without the LINQ and complicated references) and he only wants executable file. So how can we run this application on his machine without install .NET (like the setup files and stuff)????

I was thinking of virtualizing via VMware ThinApp, but I find it difficult since it requires the application to be installed, yet my professor only wants the application to be in exe format (so thinapp cannot track the changes in my system).

Any alternative? suggestions?

Comment: Could you package your app into an installer and then use ThinApp?

Comment: ill try that. thank you kobaltz, any alternatives?

Comment: :) Code your application in C++ so you don't need .NET? :)

Comment: +1 for your smart answer. but gui in C++ is hard and my program uses heaviliy those console.writeline, string functions and stuff.

Comment: You could use VisualBasic. A lot of times, you can get away without dependencies.

Comment: Also, have you tried compiling your C# app and running it on a machine without .NET installed?

Comment: ok ill try it now. tnx :) ill let u knw

Comment: What kind of machine will you be running this on? .NET has come preinstalled with nearly all Windows OSes since Media Center in 2002. Is this a non-Windows OS? **Why** does he not want .NET installed? Has he deliberately removed it already? Is this some kind of custom hardware? You can package a .NET application into a single .EXE that does not need admin access. You can include the installer with your app. You can even run a .NET app from a server via ClickOnce without installing anything at all.

Comment: windows xp  no sp. old school

Comment: @vvavepacket - C++ is just as easy as C#.  If its a console application it should be easy.  Sounds like you just need to put more effort in on your project.

Comment: "C++ is just as easy as C#." My blood pressure rose when I read that. But then I saw you are talking about console and not GUI applications.

Answer (score 3):

These solutions are not inexpensive, but:

1. [Salamander .NET Linker](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/)
2. [Spoon.net Studio](http://spoon.net/studio)

Answer (score 1):

There really is no way around this.

Well...not supported anyways. In the background .Net is really just a bunch of assemblies (dlls) - among other complex things. You COULD try to virtualize by bundling with those DLLs. Though, I'm sure this is violating some sort of license and probably won't work anyways.

I think we need to know more information on what this application does before more people scream "C++!!!!". I need this before I can actually recommend anything.

I see some advice about trying it on a system without .Net - I have tried this before and it will complain.